# How-to: Merge Windows, OS X, and Linux home folders into one (triple boot) using ntfs-3g

Tags: linux, windows, multi-boot, ntfs-3g

I'm contemplating to merge my linux home partition into c:\Users, so when I boot in Windows I have all my files in c:\Users\trusktr, and when I boot into Linux I have c:\Users mounted as my /home so that I can access my files in /home/trusktr. I'm attempting to make it easy to share files between the two OSes, including dotfiles, etc, so that things like vim and bash behave exactly the same across OSes for convenience.

I figured I'd just copy everything from linux /home into c:\users, which would result in everything having 777 permissions by default (I don't mind, I'm the only user so there's no security issue). Will this work?

Then I discovered ntfg-3g.usermap. This seems like it will allow me to do things like `chmod 655 /some/file` while in linux and it will work. I'm curious if it will also preserve all my file permissions once I've mapped my linux user to my windows user.

So, my main trouble is that I'm running ntfs-3g.usermap and it is fine until it asks me for a group ID to associate with a file, but I don't know so I press enter, then it seems to go wrong.

Here's what the output looks like. The first few `User :` and `Group :` prompts are empty because I pressed enter. Then for one I inputted 1002 for the `User :` prompt, then after that I have the problem I don't know how to handle.

```
This tool will help you to build a mapping of Windows users
to Linux users.
Be prepared to give Linux user id (uid) and group id (gid)
for owners of files which will be selected.
"/dev/sda4" opened

* Scanning "/dev/sda4" (two levels)
* Search for "Documents and Settings" and "Users"

Under Windows login "admin"
   file "AppData" has no mapped group
By which Linux login should this file be owned ?
Enter gid of login, or just press "enter" if this file
does not belong to a user, or you do not known to whom

Group :

Under Windows login "admin"
   file "Contacts" has no mapped owner
By which Linux login should this file be owned ?
Enter uid of login, or just press "enter" if this file
does not belong to a user, or you do not known to whom

User :

Under Windows login "Administrator"
   file "AppData" has no mapped group
By which Linux login should this file be owned ?
Enter gid of login, or just press "enter" if this file
does not belong to a user, or you do not known to whom

Group :

Under Windows login "Public"
   file "AppData" has no mapped group
By which Linux login should this file be owned ?
Enter gid of login, or just press "enter" if this file
does not belong to a user, or you do not known to whom

Group :

Under Windows login "trusktr"
   file "Desktop" has no mapped owner
By which Linux login should this file be owned ?
Enter uid of login, or just press "enter" if this file
does not belong to a user, or you do not known to whom

User : 1002
* Search for other directories /

   file "CORE.xml" has no mapped group
By which Linux login should this file be owned ?
Enter gid of login, or just press "enter" if this file
does not belong to a user, or you do not known to whom

Group :
"/dev/sda4" closed

You have defined no group, this can cause problems
Do you accept defining a standard group ?
y

* Creating file UserMapping
# Generated by usermap for Linux, v 1.1.4
:1002:S-1-5-21-1991058912-2816109820-761292756-513
1002:1002:S-1-5-21-2516108075-519671461-2442963378-1001
Undecided :
   S-1-5-21-2516108075-519671461-2442963378-513
   S-1-5-21-2516108075-519671461-2442963378-1002

* You will have to move the file "UserMapping"
  to directory ".NTFS-3G" after mounting
```

So the content generated after the ntfs-3g.usermap command has finished is:

```
# Generated by usermap for Linux, v 1.1.4
:1002:S-1-5-21-1991058912-2816109820-761292756-513
1002:1002:S-1-5-21-2516108075-519671461-2442963378-1001
```

Any idea what I should do?

**EDIT a few minutes later:**

When I mount the NTFS Windows partition in Linux, after setting up the UserMappings file, `ls -l /mnt/windows-partition/Users/trusktr/` shows that ownership for the files are 1002:1002. Normally, they are supposed to be 1002:100 when I'm in linux and I check with `ls -l /home/trusktr/`. So, I opened up the UserMappings file and I noticed it contains `1002:1002` followed by other stuff, so I changed it to `1002:100` and now when I list the files on the NTFS partition they show the correct ownership that match what I have in Linux.

So here's what the edited UserMappings files looks like now (the change is at the beginning of the second line):

```
# Generated by usermap for Linux, v 1.1.4
:1002:S-1-5-21-1991058912-2816109820-761292756-513
1002:100:S-1-5-21-2516108075-519671461-2442963378-1001
```

I'm still not sure what the first line in the UserMappings files is for. My guess is that it has to do with the group that owns the c:\Windows\CORE.xml file.

So hopefully this works! I will now merge over all my files from /home/trusktr into c:\Users\trusktr (along with other user folders from /home to c:\Users) using rsync then try to mount c:\Users as my /home in Linux...

**EDIT, 7 hours later:**

I've done it! I'm successfully sharing my home folders between Windows and Linux. I can boot into either OS and have the same exact files on the desktop. Now I've just gotta test it for a while and see if it's stable. I'll post an update on what I did...

**EDIT, 7 months later:**

After making the user mapping and putting it in the /.NTFS-3G folder of the windows partition, you can boot Windows no problem. For Linux, the /Users folder shall now be my home directory. This can be set up in fstab. Basically, tell it to mount the windows partition, then tell it to mount the Users folder as /home. For example:

```
# <file system> <dir>       <type> <options> <dump> <pass>

# mount the windows partition somewhere.
/dev/NTFS-part /mnt/windows ntfs-3g defaults         0 0

# then bindount the Users folder as /home.
/mnt/windows/Users /home none bind       0 0
```

**EDIT, 24 months later:**

I am now doing similar steps as above, but dual booting with Linux and OS X, using NTFS between the two with ntfs-3g. The next step is now to add Windows into the mix similarly to above, and have a triple-boot shared home folder between all three OSes. :}

Comment: You really shouldn't do this. NTFS does not support a lot of features that are important to have in your home directory.

Comment: use ext2 as home partition and mounting ext2 is now relatively well supported by windows. but please don't do that, both system does handle files differently aznd it's definitly not a good idea

Comment: @Ian Well I have all my /home files backed up, so I figure the worse thing is I'll have a mess of files to delete from c:\Users but I can still recover my /home files. Which features in particular do you think that I'll need that will be missing? And what may be the consequences?

Comment: @Kiwy The previous comment is for you too, but SO let's you only mention one person.

Comment: First NTFS has terrible performance on Linux because the driver is reverse engineered, second linux need owner/group/... the contrary is also true

Comment: Circumvent the issue by linking the resources you need in each OS.

Comment: @Kiwy Seems using ntfs-3g.usermap has allowed me user/group ownership ability, and arbitrary permissions. This is an experiment though. I'll test it out, and not rely on it, and see how it goes for a while, then move back to ext if I need to from my backup.

Comment: @Bruno9779 I was thinking about that, but I'm not sure how I'd link between ext4 and NTFS, so it's visible in Windows (e.g. c:\Users\trusktr\.bashrc -> /home/trusktr/.bashrc, don't think it's possible).

Comment: @Kiwy It's SSD so that will make up for the ntfs-3g performance loss. Also, I just booted into both Windows and Linux desktops, and my permissions and ownership seem to be just fine in both, with shared files!!. :D :D :D We'll see how it plays out...

Comment: if you manage to get it work, please post how you do. Also be aware that you could experience random file corruption and NTFS or not, perfomance will be terrible, for example try to write on usb3 disk formated in EXT4 vs NTFS on linux, the loss of efficiency is hudge

Comment: @Kiwy For sure. Thanks for the insight! I'll have to test drive it for a while and see how it does. I did notice a slower `ls -l` in some directories. And yeah, I'll be sure to update with all the details. I'm thinking of putting up a Wiki page on archlinux.org too.

Comment: Can you write the answer you promised? :)

Comment: @MilindR I updated it. I should probably post an answer with the steps. All that was left after making the mapping wad to mount the folder as /home in Linux.

Comment: On my case, I only bind (or use ln -s) Documents, Video, Music and Downloads folders between the NTFS drive and my local linux home folder. Also, I recommend to set the flag "nofail" to avoid problems with systemd + windows 8/10 fastboot enabled or a power off happens when windows is running.